# Rails test fails for asserting the presence of a link, even though it actually works on the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Hartl's rails tutorial (Chapter 10) and am writing a test to validate that all the layout links are present. This is the test file:-

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", blog_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path, count: 0
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  end
end
```

Here, the test shows the following failure:-

```
    FAIL["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 0.7809554979976383]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.78s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

If I comment out the `assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path`, it shows failure for the logout_path:-

```
 FAIL["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 0.6692811190005159]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.67s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/logout"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

This is the header partial that contains the links for users_path and logout_path:-

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><%= link_to "Blog",   blog_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

But as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1xnk.png), the Users and logout button do exist and they do work as intended.

I'm trying to figure out why the test fails even though the actual function in the application works. Help would be appreciated.

**Update:-**

The definitions for the `is_logged_in?` and `log_in_as method`:-

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user, password: 'password', remember_me: '1')
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email,
                                          password: password,
                                          remember_me: remember_me }}
  end
end
```

The definition for `logged_in?` :-

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Comment: Where does the log_in_as function come from?
Also, in the view you've got logged_in? check. Can you post source of that method. It seems like in the tests this never evaluates to true, hence the behaviour your seeing

Comment: Updated with the method definitions. I thought so too and that's why I included the is_logged_in? assertion right after, to see if the log_in_as works properly and it doesn't throw a fail. But here's the interesting bit - when I comment out the assertions for users_path and logout_path, the assertion for the login_path to have a count of 0 passes. So I guess it's logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `log_in_as` sets you up with the session variable but it does not refresh the view so you still have the original display out there.

You should do

```
assert is_logged_in?
get root_path # <- refresh the view
assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
```

Comment: This does not work due to this not being the API of assert_select.

I get: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Hash`